# NGXS state redirect user after login

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

Hi i am new in NGXS state management..in my project i have different type of users so i am trying after login redirect my user to his home page depend on user type and i have auth guard check if this user has role's name to let him go.`(userType is the role's name)`

For login i'm using login function in my state to get the token after login and update my token from null to exist token and insert it in local storage and this step `**is working very well**`

and i created a new function in auth state named it GetCurrentUser to get user data through sending his token..and the data comes well and put it in the state

Finally..

1. how can get the userType that comes from GetCurrentUser function in my AuthState and give it to service to check what his type to redirect him to his home page
2. how can i give this userType to auth guard to check the user if has the role to go to home page

---

> this is my AuthState class

---

```
import { State, Selector, Action, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Loggin , Loggout, GetCurrentUser } from '../../_actions/auth/auth.action';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth/auth.service';
import { User } from '../../_models/user';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthStateModel {
  token: string;
  user: User;
}

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'auth',
  defaults: {
      token : null,
      user:{
        email:'',
        userName:'',
        userType:'',
        firstName:'',
        lastName:''
      }
  }
})

@Injectable()
export class AuthState {

  @Selector()
  static getToken(state: AuthStateModel) {
      return state.token;
  }

  @Selector()
  static isAuthenticated(state: AuthStateModel): boolean {
    return !!state.token;
  }

  @Selector()
  static currentUser(state: AuthStateModel): User {
    return state.user
  }

  @Selector()
  static getUserType(state: AuthStateModel): string {
    return state.user.userType
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router:Router){}

  @Action(Loggin)
  login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Loggin) {
    return this.authService.Login(payload).pipe(tap(x => {
      const state = ctx.getState();
      ctx.patchState({
        ...state,
        token: x.token,
    });
    }))
  }

  @Action(GetCurrentUser)
  getcurrentUser(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    return this.authService.getCurrentUser().pipe(tap((x:User) => {
      ctx.patchState({
        user:{
          email: x.email,
          userType: x.userType,
          userName: x.userName,
          firstName: x.firstName,
          lastName: x.lastName
        }
      });
    }))
  }

  @Action(Loggout)
  logout(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    this.router.navigate(['auth2/login']);
    localStorage.removeItem('auth.token');
    ctx.setState({
      token: null,
      user:{
        email: null,
        userType: null,
        userName: null,
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null
      }
  });
  }
}
```

---

> this is my login function in login component

---

```
login(){
if (this.loginForm.valid) {
  this.prepairLoginModel();
  this.store.dispatch(new Loggin(this.loginModel))
 }
}
```

---

> this is my auth guard

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth/auth.service';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { AuthState } from '../_states/auth/auth.state';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { GetCurrentUser } from '../_actions/auth/auth.action';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authServic:AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private store:Store,
    private location: Location
    ){}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      const isAuthenticated = this.store.selectSnapshot(AuthState.isAuthenticated);
      const userType = this.store.selectSnapshot(AuthState.getUserType);

      if(!isAuthenticated){
        return  from(this.router.navigate(['auth2']));
      }

      return true
  }

}
```

---

> this is my from my app-routing.modules

---

```
 {
    path: 'company',
    data:{permittedRoles:'Company'},
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/users/company/company.module').then(m => m.CompanyModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'agent',
    data:{permittedRoles:'Agent'},
     loadChildren: () => import('./views/users/agent/agent.module').then(m => m.AgentModule)
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same task before and here is my solution for this issue ,
my action is as following

```
export namespace Auth {
  export class Login {
    static readonly type = '[Auth] Login';
    constructor(public payload: { username: string; password: string }) { }
  }

  export class Logout {
    static readonly type = '[Auth] Logout';
  }

  export class CheckSession {
    static type = '[Auth] CheckSession';
  }
  export class LogoutSuccess {
    static type = '[Auth] LogoutSuccess';
  }

  // Events
  export class LoginRedirect {
    static type = '[Auth] LoginRedirect';
  }

  export class LoginSuccess {
    static type = '[Auth] LoginSuccess';
    constructor(public jwt: JsonWebToken) { }
  }
  export class LoginFailed {
    static type = '[Auth] LoginFailed';
    constructor(public error: any) { }
  }
}
```

and corresponding state is as following

```
@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'auth',
  defaults: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    username: '',
    userId: '',
    isSuperUser: false,
    isLoading: false,
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static token(state: AuthStateModel): string {
    return state.token;
  }
  @Selector()
  static refreshToken(state: AuthStateModel): string {
    return state.refreshToken;
  }
  @Selector()
  static username(state: AuthStateModel): string {
    return state.username;
  }
  @Selector()
  static isSuperUser(state: AuthStateModel): boolean {
    return state.isSuperUser;
  }
  @Selector()
  static isLoading(state: AuthStateModel): boolean {
    return state.isLoading;
  }
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  @Action(Auth.Login)
  login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Auth.Login) {
    ctx.patchState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    return this.authService.login(payload).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        ctx.dispatch(new Auth.LoginSuccess(res));
      },
      (error) => {
        ctx.dispatch(new Auth.LoginFailed(error));
      }
    );
  }

  @Action(Auth.Logout)
  logout(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    return this.authService.logOut(state.token).subscribe(() => {
      ctx.dispatch(new Auth.LogoutSuccess());
    });
  }

  @Action(Auth.LoginRedirect)
  onLoginRedirect(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    console.log('onLoginRedirect, navigating to /auth/login');
    ctx.dispatch(new Navigate(['/sign-in']));
  }

  @Action(Auth.LoginSuccess)
  onLoginSuccess(
    ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>,
    payload: Auth.LoginSuccess
  ) {
    console.log('onLoginSuccess, navigating to /dashboard');
    ctx.patchState({
      token: payload.jwt.accessToken,
      userId: payload.jwt.id,
      isSuperUser: payload.jwt.isSuper,
      refreshToken: payload.jwt.refreshToken,
      isLoading: false
    });
    payload.jwt.isSuper?
        ctx.dispatch(new Navigate(['/dashboard'])):
        ctx.dispatch(new Navigate(['/userHome']));
  }

  @Action([Auth.LoginFailed, Auth.LogoutSuccess])
  setUserStateOnFailure(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    ctx.patchState({
      token: null,
      refreshToken: null,
      username: '',
      userId: '',
      isSuperUser: false,
      isLoading: false
    });
    ctx.dispatch(new Auth.LoginRedirect());
  }
}
```

and finally this is my authguard

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store) { }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.store.selectOnce(AuthState.token).pipe(
      map(u => {
        if (!u) {
          this.store.dispatch(new Auth.LoginRedirect());
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Hopefully you found your baby.